# AS3 Array 1 to 100

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having trouble finding a way to do an array that doesn't make me type all the numbers , for example :
(i found this code online)

```
var array:Array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
var odds:Array=[],
evens:Array=[],
odds_sum:int=0,
evens_sum:int=0
;

for(var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] % 2 == 1){
        odds.push(array[i]);
        odds_sum += array[i];
    } else {
        evens.push(array[i]);
        evens_sum += array[i];
    }
}

trace(odds);        
trace(odds_sum);    
trace(evens);       
trace(evens_sum);
```

i wanted the code to trace all the numbers between 1 and 100 (including the 1 and 100) but don't have to type them all down.
Help solving this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous , If you simply need all the numbers between 1 and 100 you simply do

```
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    trace(i);
}
```

or if you want them in your array

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++){
     arr.push(i);
}
```

or if you want odd and even numbers in separate array

```
var odds:Array = new Array();
var evens:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i%2==0)
       evens.push(i);
    else     
       odds.push(i);
}
```

where the array odds/even have appropriate numbers between 1 and 100.